# Same path Router switching in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I recently started learning express, I want to switch between external router with same path such as ([www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)), in first time visiting it take role as login page but after logged in it will change for the home page.

- Sorry for my weakness in English, codes may help to understand my error.
- **First part**: briefly, **Second part**: full info.

***FIRST PART***

Matter codes in **server.js** (start point)

```
server.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('loginPageDemo');
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")});

const guestRouter = require('./routers/guest');

server.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{  // Problem point
    if(req.body.guestBtn = "guestBtn"){
        // switch to guest router
    }
});
```

All codes in **guest.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var guestRouter = express();

guestRouter.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
    res.send('you are guest');
});

module.exports = guestRouter;
```

---

***SECOND PART***

Login Page with ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <Title>login page</Title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
            <input required type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="guestBtn" value="guest">Continue as guest</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

server.js: check // PROBLEM POINT in line 13 and line 21

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const server = express();

server.use(express.static('public'));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

server.get('/',(req,res)=>{ // PROBLEM POINT
    res.render('loginPageDemo');
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")});

const adminRouter = require('./routers/admin');
const userRouter = require('./routers/user');
const guestRouter = require('./routers/guest');

server.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{  // PROBLEM POINT
    if(req.body.guestBtn = "guestBtn"){
    // switch to guest router
    //
    // res.redirect(guestRouter); // OUTPUT ==> Cannot GET /function(req,%20res,%20next)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20app.handle(req,%20res,%20next);%0A%20%20%7D
    // res.redirect(guestRouter(req, res, next)); // OUTPUT ==> Cannot GET /undefined
    // server.use(guestRouter); //NOT WORKING, stayed in LoginPageDemo.ejs.      
    }
});

// server.use(adminRouter);
// server.use(userRouter);
server.listen(process.env.PORT,(err)=>console.log(err ? err:"Server started in "+process.env.PORT+" PORT"));
```

guest.js

```
var express = require('express');
var guestRouter = express();

guestRouter.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
    res.send('you are guest');
});

module.exports = guestRouter;
```

Comment: You need to authorize user and check if he is already login in your `/` route. If not redirect to login page or home page depending on this logic. To redirect you can use  `res.redirect("/home")`

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat I want to switch between routers that control same path(link). this problem done because server.get('/', callBackFuncton()) take control over loaclhost:port/ and don't let guestRouter.get('/', callBackFunction()) take control and change the page content, I want to turn off server.get() and turn on server.use(guestRouter). THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER

Comment: if your problem resolved by the answer, accept the answer to help others to get the solution

Comment: @subrahmanya bhat, Unfortunately it doesn't do what I want, and I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is less than 15. If I get the answe I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{  // PROBLEM POINT
    if(req.body.guestBtn = "guestBtn"){
    // switch to guest router
    //
    // res.redirect(guestRouter); // OUTPUT ==> Cannot GET /function(req,%20res,%20next)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20app.handle(req,%20res,%20next);%0A%20%20%7D
    // res.redirect(guestRouter(req, res, next)); // OUTPUT ==> Cannot GET /undefined
    // server.use(guestRouter); //NOT WORKING, stayed in LoginPageDemo.ejs.      
    }
});
```

You are doing  `res.redirect()` wrongly. `res.redirect()`  will take route as parameter but you are sending imported object directly.

```
server.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{  // PROBLEM POINT
        if(req.body.guestBtn = "guestBtn"){
         res.redirect("/guestRoute")
     }
})
```

and in your guest.js you should have proper route suffix
guest.js

```
var express = require('express');
var guestRouter = express();

guestRouter.get('/guestRoute', (req,res,next) => {
    res.send('you are guest');
});

module.exports = guestRouter;
```

incase you want to use route files with proper route suffix, use it like

```
server.use("/guest",guestrouter)
```

and in your guest.js file

```
guestRouter.get('/route1', (req,res,next) => {
    res.send('you are guest');
});

guestRouter.get('/route2', (req,res,next) => {
    res.send('you are guest');
});
```

now your entire uri would be

```
<your-domain>/guest/route1. etc
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER @subrahmanyabhat but I want to switch between routers that control same path(link). this problem done because server.get('/', callBackFuncton()) take control over loaclhost:port/ and don't let guestRouter.get('/', callBackFunction()) take control and change the page content, I want to turn off server.get() and turn on server.use(guestRouter). **I want to do that, if continue as guest or logged in by user account or admin account redirect them to the same path, but different content by serving with different routers. (I do it as practice not project) **